# How to corect work with 'process.stdin' in node 'worker_threads'

Tags: node.js

How to correct work with *process.stdin* in node *worker_threads* ...
I want to enter some value (code), but is stoped on input .. ?
tried 2 methods, but both same, stopped on input.

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

(async () => {
    if (isMainThread) {

        const worker = new Worker(__filename, {
            stdin: true,
            // stdout: true,
            workerData: { text: 'Enter Code: ' }
        });

    } else {

        console.log(workerData.text);

        // Method-1
        // answer = await new Promise(resolve => {
        //     process.stdin.once('data', (chunk) => {
        //         const code = chunk.toString().trim();
        //         console.log(`Captcha Code : ${code}`);
        //         resolve(code);
        //     });
        // });


        // Method-2
        const readline = require('readline');
        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: process.stdin,
            output: process.stdout
        });

        answer = await new Promise(resolve => {
            rl.question('Code: ', (answer) => {
                console.log(`Answer: ${answer}`);
                rl.close();
                resolve(answer);
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  It will not work to have multiple worker threads all trying to read and process data from stdin.

Comment: I agree, but practically how to do correctly?

Comment: WHAT are you trying to accomplish?  We can't help until we know what you're actually trying to do.  Why are you even trying to use threads for such a simple and low load action?